# Where was Zod in the Phantom Zone?

Tags: the-lego-batman-movie

Early in *The Lego Batman Movie*, Superman mentions that he banished Zod to the Phantom Zone.

Later on, Batman

> steals the banishing tool and sends Joker to the Phantom Zone. Joker
>  eventually sets all the bad guys in the Phantom Zone free to wreak
>  havok on Lego Gotham.

However, I do not recall seeing Zod either in the Phantom Zone or in Lego Gotham.

Superman banished Zod to the Phantom Zone: where was he during the remainder of the movie?

Comment: Just saw this last night and it just seems like a regular ol' plot hole unfortunately.

Comment: @TylerShads that was my impression as well, but who knows? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: That's because the bad guys simply just ate him.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152760/in-lego-batman-where-is-zod/181566#181566 Question from sister site that has an answer, rep goes to Valorum.

Comment: @JamesD why not answer it then here

Answer (score 2):

**Zod was in the Phantom Zone.** You see him later in the film as part of Joker's Army of Evil™.

[image: screenshot showing the Joker's Army of Evil]

Note that there are multiple villains who turn up in the later scenes *who don't appear in the earlier scene inside the Phantom Zone*. Clearly they were only intended to be a cross-section of the inmates rather than the entire population.

Note that this is the answer as from [In Lego batman where is Zod?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152760/in-lego-batman-where-is-zod/181566#181566)